# I have a VPS running on a single IP, can I redirect domains to ports or do I need separate IPs?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, node.js

The situation may be resolved by my intention to purchase an IPv6 prefix for the VPS, but in the mean time I'd quite like to know if this is possible.

Basically what I want to achieve is a simple interface to Node.JS apps running on the VPS via domain names, so that for instance I could have "steak.chaos-kitten.com" pointing to one node.js app and "lister.chaos-kitten.com" pointing to another, and perhaps "chaos-kitten.com" itself pointing to a third.

I know you can't use DNS to point to a specific port, but is there some software solution I can employ that will redirect incoming GET requests to the appropriate node.js app based on the domain name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technology you're looking for is a proxy server. It sits in front of your backend, accepts connections for the relevant domains using something like name based virtual hosting and proxies them off to the ports you define. You can use [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html), [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule) or even [node](http://www.catonmat.net/http-proxy-in-nodejs/) itself as a proxy.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was thinking of.  Thanks so much! :)